# Get the attribute value of each element from a jQuery set, into an array

Tags: jquery, attributes, jquery-selectors

How can I get all attributes (e.g. `href`) of all elements matching a jQuery selector?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
var ids = [];

$('.myClass').each(function () {
  ids.push($(this).attr('id')); // ids.push(this.id) would work as well.
});
```

Comment: Why are you creating a jQuery object (`$(this).attr('id')`) rather than simply the native `this.id`?

Comment: @David Thomas - force of habit more than anything else, probably, but I'll amend the answer.

Comment: @DavidThomas: `this.id` only works for the `id` attribute because `this` is a DOM note. For the general case, e.g. `href`, you need either `this.getAttribute('href')` or `$(this).attr('href')`.

Answer (score 33):

Something like

```
var idArray = $(".someClass").map(function(){
    return this.id
}).get().join(',');
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zPt7J/)

Answer (score 2):

One-liner with ES6 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), using jQuery [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```js
const ids = $('a.someClass').map((i, el) => el.getAttribute('href')).get();

console.log(ids);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="test1" class="someClass">t1</a>
<a href="test2" class="someClass">t2</a>
<a href="test3" class="someClass">t3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**More simple solution with Underscore.js**

For example: Get all links text who's parents have class `someClass`

```
_.pluck($('.someClass').find('a'), 'text');
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htfL3d4g/1/)