# Grab values of an attribute from all elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

Suppose we have the following HTML:

```
<entries>
  <entry id="1" />
  <entry id="2" />
  <entry id="3" />
  <entry id="4" />
</entries>
```

Does jQuery have a built-in mechanism for retrieving all values of a specific attribute? And if not, then what is the most efficient way to retrieve them?

Eg, something similar to: `$('entry').attrs('id')`, returning a list of values across all elements which returns something similar to `["1", "2", "3", "4"]`?

jQuery documentation under [General Attributes](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/general-attributes/) (which is where `attr` is found,) doesn't give any hint to such a thing existing, and I've found nothing on StackOverflow or any other support forum asking this question.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no something like this in jquery, you can use https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/                         
$("input[placeholder]").each( function () {
    console.log($(this));
});

Comment: There is a solution from another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5327980/4173464

Comment: `.each` is gross - use `.map` https://stackoverflow.com/a/5327994/1555990

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend jQuery using [`jQuery.fn.extend()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fn.extend/) and add a custom method that iterates over all matching elements, extracting a single or multiple attributes from all of them and pushes/merges them into the returned array/object, respectively.

As the implementation is vanilla JS, this will be faster than working with jQuery objects and functions in all intermediate steps, but might need some tuning depending on which browsers you need to support:

```js
jQuery.fn.extend({
  attrs: function(attributeName) {
    if (attributeName) {
        return this.toArray().map((el) => el.getAttribute(attributeName));
    }
    
    return this.toArray().reduce((merged, el) => {
      const { attributes } = el;
      const totalAttributes = attributes.length;

      for (let i = 0; i < totalAttributes; ++i) {  
        const attribute = attributes[i].nodeName;

        if (merged[attribute]) {
          merged[attribute].push(el.getAttribute(attribute));
        } else {
          merged[attribute] = [el.getAttribute(attribute)];
        }
      }

      return merged;
    }, {});
  },
});

console.log($('entry').attrs());
console.log($('entry').attrs('id'));
console.log($('entry').attrs('class'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<entries>
  <entry id="1" class="foo" />
  <entry id="2" class="bar" />
  <entry id="3" class="baz" />
  <entry id="4" class="qux" />
</entries>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @That1Guy This is probably faster, more flexible and scales better than a solution using jQuery in all intermediate steps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like that: https://jsfiddle.net/g903dyp6/

```
<entries>
  <entry id="1" />
  <entry id="2" />
  <entry id="3" />
  <entry id="4" />
</entries>

let arr = $.map($('entry'), function(el) {
     return $(el).attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is not a direct function to do that. However, it can be easily accomplished using [.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/). E.g.,

```
let ids = $('entry').map(function() {
    return this.getAttribute('id');
}).get();
```

```js
let ids = $('entry').map(function() {
    return this.getAttribute('id');
}).get();

console.log(ids);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<entries>
  <entry id="1" />
  <entry id="2" />
  <entry id="3" />
  <entry id="4" />
</entries>
```

Comment: How well does this scale? Say you have 5,000-10,000  `entry` tags - what does the performance look like in a situation like that? Is there a better solution in that case?

Comment: @That1Guy I'm not certain. Jsperf is giving trouble.

Comment: FYI rather than wrapping the element in a jQuery object to get the attribute's value (eg `$(this).attr('id')`, you can simply do `this.getAttribute('id')`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way that uses the JavaScript Array .map() function:

```js
let ids = jQuery.makeArray($('entry')).map(entry => entry.id);

console.log('ids:', ids);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<entries>
  <entry id="1" />
  <entry id="2" />
  <entry id="3" />
  <entry id="4" />
</entries>
```